# calculate average and maximum value for subset of rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, dataframe

I have dataframe that looks like:

```
 date       session     time         x1          x2     x3    x4      x5     x6   
 2015-05-22      1     morning       Tom         129     1     129    45     67
 2015-05-22      1     morning       Kate         0      1     670    89     34   
 2015-05-22      1     noon          GroupeId     0      1     45     56    13
 2015-05-26      2     noon          Hence        129    1     167    7     13
 2015-05-26      2     evening       Kate         0            987    876    478
 2015-05-26      3     night         Julie        0      1     567            8
```

So I need to calculate the average and maximume value per column for each session, i.e. to have the average of values X2 for each session(first, second or third in example, but in real dataframe I have much more rows and sessions), the maximum of values x4 for X4, the sum of the values x3 for each session. I found a lot of examples for average of several columns, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for, as you see. I tried some  methods like: `multi_df.groupby(level=1).sum().to_csv('output.csv', sep='\t')` for multilevel dataframe that I tried create with this by `multi_df=df.set_index(['session','index'], inplace=False)` but it doesn't give me the result that could make sens

so any advice or example of transformation like those I'm looking for, is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? (i.e. a way to aggregate with specific functions per column?).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.io.parsers.read_csv('temp.txt', sep = '\t')

df_agg = df.groupby('session').agg({
    'x2' : np.mean,
    'x3' : np.sum,
    'x4' : np.min,
    })

# you can apply more than one function to a column like so:

df_agg_multifunc = df.groupby('session').agg({
    'x2' : [np.mean, np.std],
    'x3' : [np.sum, np.std],
    'x4' : [np.min, np.std],
    })
```